# InvalidPathException: Illegal char when I use Lint

Tags: android, lint

I have the problem. but I delete a cached file under the build/intermediates directory , I still have the problem, `InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 30: F:\studio_sdk\platform-tools;F:\studio_sdk\tools;\extras\android\m2repository`，How to solve it?Thank you

Comment: Did you try to invalidate cache and/or restart?

Comment: yes ,still not good